# Error while installing chrome app - Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''wasm-eval''

Tags: google-chrome-app, content-security-policy

While installing packaged chrome app from chrome://extensions I get the below error :
"The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''wasm-eval''. It will be ignored. Context, main.html Stack Trace main.html:0 (anonymous function)". The app is build in angular 1.6 and runs a webview which pulls files from a folder that is packaged withing app itself

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.